# Robolectric: run looper of handler in my case

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a very simple class which has a `Handler`, when it handles message it sends new message again:

```
public class MyRepeatTask{
  …
  public void startTask() {
    // send message with delay 5 sec
    handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(…), 5000);
  }

  Handler  handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // I put a log for unit test
            System.out.println(“handling message …”);
            // send message with delay again
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(…), 5000);
        }
  }
}
```

As you see above, when `startTask()` is called, the handler starts sending a message in 5 seconds. Then, in `handleMessage()` callback, the `handler` again send a message with 5 seconds delay. The purpose of this is to repeatedly do some task(like `System.out.println()`).

I test the above class with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyRepeatTaskTest {
  @Test
  public void testStartTask() {
    MyRepeatTask task = new MyRepeatTask();
    task.startTask();

    // run looper of ‘handler’ in task
    ShadowLooper shadowLooper = Shadows.shadowOf(task.handler.getLooper());
    shadowLooper.runToEndOfTasks();

    // sleep for 30 seconds
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
  }
}
```

I expect to see the `System.out.println()` message “`handling message …`” every 5 seconds. However, when I run my test, I only see the message **once** in terminal.

It looks like the `handler` ’s `Looper` has only run for **one** task, then it stopped.

If I am right, how to keep the looper running all the time in Robolectric? If I am wrong, why I only see one log message?

**========== UPDATE ===========**

I tried @rds 's answer, I replaced `Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);` by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   shadowLooper.runToEndOfTasks();
}
```

Now I can see N times “`handling message …`”. BUT, the whole test is not simulating the delay. I have 5 seconds delay when sending message with `handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(…), 5000)`, is it so that Robolectric framework doesn't simulate this kind of delay message at all??? How can I have the delay in my test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `runToEndOfTasks();` there is at this stage only one task.

Instead of letting the test thread sleep, you should call `shadowLooper.runToEndOfTasks();` N times to have N calls of your handler.

Comment: This is also a more robust test, and that's why Robolectric works like this. Depending on the time that your code takes to execute, you don't know how many iterations will be executed in 30 seconds, but the tests knows exactly how many times `runToEndOfTasks()` was called.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean I should replace the thread sleep by a for loop which calls runToEndOfTasks() N times? `for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++){shadowLooper.runToEndOfTasks();}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. A test should not depend on real time. If you want to test that your app has a different behaviour with time, use [ShadowSystemClock](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSystemClock.html) or inject a clock that you can mock. For instance, add in the loop `shoadowClock.sleep(5000)` since you know the real implementation sleeps 5000ms beetween each background task.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar problems when implementing a scheduled download from api-webservice. I implemented a timer instead in addition to a handler. I used this to do a task each day (or in you case in several seconds). You can also set the number of times...

[Timer Reference Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [`ShadowLooper#idle(long)`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLooper.html#idle-long-). This will allow you to carefully advance the time of the handler and assert if the task is being run or not at different intervals.